# Complicated observable array sorting

Tags: angular, observable

I have an observable array, `clientService.clients$`, that I'd like to sort but it seems as though nothing happens when I try to sort it:

```
sortClients(method : string) : void {

  console.log(method)

  this.clientService.clients$.pipe(
    map( clients => {
      console.log(clients);
      sorted = []
      for ( let type of this.appointment_types ) {
        let apps = this.clients[type];
        if (method == 'name') {
          sorted = _.sortBy(apps, (client) => {
            if (client && client.name) {
              return _.last(client.name.split(" "))
            }
          })
        } else {
          sorted = apps.sort((a, b) => {
            return new Date(a['time']).valueOf() - new Date(b['time']).valueOf()
          })
          // console.log(sorted)
        }
      }
    })
  );
```

And I'd like to avoid storing the value of `clients` in this component and simply modify the value of `clients$` so that I can include it in my view as an observable.

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let clientGroup of clientService.clients$ | async | keyvalue; let i = index;" class="awaken-striped">

  <client-index-row
    *ngFor="let client of clientGroup.value"
    [client]="client"
    [type]="type"
    (clientSelected)="itemTapped($event)"
  ></client-index-row>

</ion-list>
```

I know something is wrong because I cannot `subscribe` to the result of `map` but I'm not sure how to correct that.  Also, I see `console.log(method)` in my console, but I **don't** see `console.log(clients)`

Comment: You are not returning `sorted` from `map`, the function `map` expects you to return the (mutated) data.

Comment: When I add `return sorted` to the end of `map` nothing changes.

Comment: You also need to do something with the result of the `pipe`. It is applied to the *result* which you then need to assign back to something or use directly. See my answer below. Also do make sure to call `sortClients`, I mention that only because there is no code in your question that does this and I have to assume it is done in code not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are not returning `sorted` from `map`, the function `map` expects you to return the (mutated) data.
2. The result of operators called in `pipe` also needs to be applied / assigned to something. In this case they are being ignored, if the types match (returned from map) you can reassign back to `client$` or you can assign to a new local field.

```
sortClients(method : string) : void {

  console.log(method)

  this.clients$ = this.clientService.clients$.pipe(
    map( clients => {
      console.log(clients);
      sorted = []
      for ( let type of this.appointment_types ) {
        let apps = this.clients[type];
        if (method == 'name') {
          sorted = _.sortBy(apps, (client) => {
            if (client && client.name) {
              return _.last(client.name.split(" "))
            }
          })
        } else {
          sorted = apps.sort((a, b) => {
            return new Date(a['time']).valueOf() - new Date(b['time']).valueOf()
          })
          // console.log(sorted)
        }
      }
      // added
      return sorted;
    })
  );
```

Now access the field from the component instead of the service. This assumes that the `sortClients` method has been called so that `$clients` is not `undefined`.

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let clientGroup of clients$ | async | keyvalue; let i = index;" class="awaken-striped">
```

Comment: It still doesn't seem to enter `map` cause `console.log(clients)` is still not logged

Comment: Also it doesn't look like the docs return anything https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html

Comment: @JeremyThomas - they do but if you omit the braces `{}` because you only have a single Line of Code the return is implied.

Comment: maybe check if `this.clientService.clients$` is not `undefined` maybe that's why you don't enter the `pipe` or `map` method